# How do I set a 40X error with a custom message on JAX-RS Exception?

Tags: java, xml, exception, xmlhttprequest, jax-rs

I'm working on a Web Service on JAX-RS that is already working. Now I'm looking for the way to catch some Exceptions in order to send an 40X error with a custom message to the user.

I have a web service, and an ExceptionMapper.

This is my web service:

```
@Path( value = "/test/")
public interface ServiceTest {

    @Path(value = "{rrf}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public ObjectDTO getDealer(@PathParam("rrf") String rrf){
        ObjectDTO objectDTO = new ObjectDTO();
        if( verifyRRFSintax(rrf) ) {
            //Get the objet, this part works fine
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Custom message");
        } 
        return dwsDTO;
    }

    private boolean verifyRRFSintax(String rrf) {
        return rrf.matches("[0-9]{8}");
    }
}
```

This is my ExceptionMapper

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public class IllegalArgumentExceptionMapper 
    implements ExceptionMapper<IllegalArgumentException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }
}
```

and this is how it's registed on the application-context.xml file

```
<bean id="serviceTest" class="ServiceTest"/>

<jaxrs:server id="Server" address="/ws">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="serviceTest"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean id="rffErrorException" class="IllegalArgumentExceptionMapper"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

When I debug, the IllegalArgumentExceptionMapper catches the Exception I throw but I don't see the message on a yellow web page that is shown on the browser. I always have a

> Erreur d'analyse XML : aucun élément trouvé / XML Parsing Error: no
>   element found (in english)

How I can make to show this custom message on the browser?
Why, even if I change the kind of Response Status (NOT_FOUND, BAD_REQUEST, FORBIDDEN), this yellow page is always the same?

PD: On the console I have in a message "out.handlemessage" that is printed when the Mapper catch the exception.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks, I finally found what I need: I add a Custom Exception like:

public class DwsWebServiceException extends WebApplicationException {

    public DwsWebServiceException(String message, int status) {
        super(Response.status(status).entity(message).type(MediaType.TEXT_XML).build());
    }
}

and it's showing the message.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND)// Or another Status
                .entity("Error Message").build());
```

Comment: I don't know about other JAX-RS implementations, but for me, with RestEasy 3.0x, this will not work. It fails silently and no response is received by the client. You need to add `.type( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )` to the method chain in your `Response` builder, otherwise it seems to choke on the String "entity".

Comment: Thanks, @Lambart, I've found this thanks to your comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628897/dropwizard-exception-handling-giving-custom-error-json-error-messages-to-clie

Comment: @FerranMaylinch Happy to be of assistance. I see that I've previously upvoted that question and answer, myself. :)