# Dropwizard : Exception Handling, giving custom error JSON error messages to client

Tags: java, json, dropwizard

How can i configure dropwizard to give custom error messages to User.
If my function is supposed to return a object myObject, but since there is an error, it should throw and exception and return a error Object to User with a custom message.

Answer (score 12):

You can add your own subclass of `WebApplicationException` like this:

```java
public class ObjectNotFoundException extends WebApplicationException {

  public ObjectNotFoundException() {
    super(Responses.notFound().build());
  }

  public ObjectNotFoundException(String message) {
    super(Response.status(Responses.NOT_FOUND).
    entity(message).type("text/plain").build());
  }

}
```

See [the documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e5155) for more information. You can also use `ExceptionMappers` if that makes more sense for your application.

Comment: Sorry, had to make an edit to undo the accidental downvote I made an hour ago (or so)